# How to merge items based on first element in a python nested list and at the same time sum specific items and combine last item by dashes?

Tags: python, merge, nested-lists

I am new to Python and I am working on nested list in python. I am actually trying to integrate multiple operations within a nested list of items. I am not sure how to execute everything to achieve intended output.

I have this nested list

```
lst = [['ABC', 'A-1', 10, 1], ['BCD', 'B-1', 5, 1], ['ABC', 'A-1', 15, 2], ['ABC', 'B-1', 3, 3], ['BCD', 'B-1', 20, 4], ['ABC', 'A-1', 5, 4]]
```

I am planning to do the following things within the nested list.

1. If the first two elements of list within the nested list are same, then I have to sum the third element and combine fourth element by dashes(-). So, for example, three of the lists within the nested lists would merge and become

   ['ABC', 'A-1', 30, '1-2-4']
2. Then, For each of the existing lists, if first element is same, I had to merge them based on first element. So I get the final output as mentioned below.

   output = [['ABC', ['A-1', 30, '1-2-4'], ['B-1', 3, '3']], ['BCD', ['B-1', 25, '1-4']]]

Comment: Please add your attempt at a solution, stack overflow is not a site for people making your code for you; you wouldn't have learned anything that way

Answer (score 0):

You can use `collections.defaultdict`:

```
import collections
lst = [['ABC', 'A-1', 10, 1], ['BCD', 'B-1', 5, 1], ['ABC', 'A-1', 15, 2], ['ABC', 'B-1', 3, 3], ['BCD', 'B-1', 20, 4], ['ABC', 'A-1', 5, 4]]
d = collections.defaultdict(dict)
for a, b, *c in lst:
   if b not in d[a]:
      d[a][b] = [c]
   else:
      d[a][b].append(c)

result = [[a, *[[j, sum((l:=[*zip(*k)])[0]), '-'.join(map(str, l[1]))] for j, k in b.items()]] 
           for a, b in d.items()]
```

Output:

```
[['ABC', ['A-1', 30, '1-2-4'], ['B-1', 3, '3']], ['BCD', ['B-1', 25, '1-4']]]
```